# Fastest way to perform rotational transformations on a chain of dependent, attached objects

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, opengl, eigen

Suppose I have two (two for the example, it will actually be some n > 1) sort of rectangular prisms "attached to each other" such that the 4 vertices on their adjacent faces are the same vertex in memory.  So like two wooden blocks, one stacked on the other, with 4 vertices on the bottom, 4 in the middle that are shared between the two, and 4 on the top.  Now, I want to be able to first do a specific rotation on the "top" wooden block, as if it were on a hinge that has a centerpoint of those 4 shared vertices.

So like an elbow, let's say it can only flex up to 45 degrees at a specific angle, and to perform the rotation I rotate the 8 vertices that make up the object around that invisible hinge center point.  In the process, the 4 shared vertices of the other block get somewhat moved, but since the hinge is the center point among them they aren't getting "translated" away from the bottom block.  I guess calling them wooden is counter-intuitive, since they will morph in specific ways, but I was trying to set it up to visualize.  Anyway, let's say I want to be able to rotate this bottom block in a different manner, but have the top block act like it is attached.  Thus, if the bottom block moves, the top block is swung around with it, but *also* with whatever flex it has on the hinge between them.

I was considering incrementally doing the transformations either via axis angle or quaternions, starting with the "top most" block and working my way down the dependency chain, performing the rotation on the current block and every vertex on blocks "above" it.  However, this would require messing with offsetting all the vertices to put the current hinge as the origin, performing the rotation, then reversing the previous offset, for each step in this chain.  Is there a more efficient way of handling this?  I mean efficiency in speed, having extra preprocessed data in memory isn't a big deal.  There may also come a time when I can't count on having such a linear dependency chain (such as the top block ends up being attached to the bottom block to form a ring, perhaps).  What would be the proper way to handle this for these kind of possibilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me from your description that you basically want something like a long piece of "jello", i.e., if the top section of the block/prism moves, then there is some secondary movement in the rest of the segments of the block/prism-chain, sort of like how moving a chain or some soft-body will create secondary-movements in the rest of the segments that make-up the chain or ring.

If that is the case, then I suggest actually constructing some "bones", where each bone segment starts and ends at the center-point of the 4-vertices that make-up each start and end-face of the prism/blocks.  Then you can calculate when you move one segment of the bone-chain, how much the other bones in the chain should move relative to the bone that was moved.  From there, you can weight the rest of the vertices in the prism/block against this central "bone" so that they move the appropriate amount as the bone moves.  You may also want to average the vertices attached to one "bone" against another bone segment as well so that there is a fall-off in the weight of the attached vertices, creating a smoother movement if you end up with too much pinching at each "joint".

Using bones with the vertices weighed against the bones should reduce the number of rotational transforms you need to calculate.  Only the movement of the bone-joints needs the heavy-lifting calculations ... the vertices themselves are simply interpolated from the location of the bones in the chain.

Comment: It's actually not about propagating movement of one through the rest of the chain in some natural fashion.  I was just wondering if there was a faster way to propagate the accumulation of hinge rotations down the chain of dependency.  Like it starts with raising your arm at the shoulder, then your elbow is bent 30 degrees, wrist twisted 20 degrees.  Is there a faster way than doing axis angle/quaternion rotation first on the hand for wrist hinge, then on the collective lower arm/hand for the elbow hinge, then on the upper arm/lower arm/hand for shoulder?

Comment: Forward kinematics (what you're describing, where you transform the child first and then the parent) will be the fastest way, so no, there is nothing really faster out there.  The thing about using a "bones" system though is that you won't have to apply every transform to each and every vertex.  The bones are the only ones getting the complicated rotation matrices applied to them, and the vertices are just interpolated from the new location of the bones.

Comment: Ah, ok, I was representing stuff as "bones" like you are describing, except only originally for generating the vertices.  This should work then, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an existing tool. Have a look at this question about linking rigid bodies:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19724/how-to-represent-the-effect-of-linking-rigid-bodies-together

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to handle an articulated, single-ended chain is [skeletal animation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_animation) -- using a chain of "bone" elements (defined by a relative translation/rotation relation), with the option of doing linear interpolation based on the bones to determine the position of the "skin" vertices.  (Note that you will need to determine the rotation angle of each "joint" to fully define the pose.)

A ring of elements is more difficult to handle, because you can no longer define the rotation of each joint independently of all others.  To solve this problem, set up a physical simulation or other solver which includes all the constraints.  Exactly what to do depends on how you need to manipulate the object -- if it's part of a game engine, physical simulation makes sense, but if it's to be hand-animated, you have a wide range of possibilities for semi-automated rigging (keyword: reverse-kinematic).